# JavaScript is not being rendered in JSP

Tags: javascript, json, jsp

I have the following JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@ page import="org.json.JSONObject"%>
<%@ page import="org.json.JSONArray"%>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Welcome <%=request.getAttribute("resultset")%></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Login successful!!!</h3>
    <h4>
        Hello,
        <%=request.getAttribute("jsondata")%> 
    </h4>
    <p>------------</p>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = <%=request.getAttribute("jsondata")%>;
    document.write($.parseJSON(data));
    var seriesOptions = [];

        // Populate series
        for (i = 0; i < data.DeltaRealTime.length; i++){
            seriesOptions[i] = {
                name: data.DeltaRealTime[i].name,
                data: [data.DeltaRealTime[i].key, parseFloat(data.DeltaRealTime[i].value)]
            };
        }

        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'spline',
                animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                marginRight: 10,

                events: {
                    load: function() {

                        // set up the updating of the chart each second
                        setInterval(function() {

                                // Populate series
                                for (i = 0; i < data.DeltaRealTime.length; i++){
                                    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
                                    chart.series[i].addPoint([data.DeltaRealTime[i].key, parseFloat(data.DeltaRealTime[i].value)]);
                                }
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: "Valori Delta"
            },
            xAxis: {
            [...]
            series: seriesOptions
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I run my application, only "Hello", and the JSON-values are printed and the dotted line "---". The JavaScript is just transferred raw into the HTML code :/

If I change

```
document.write($.parseJSON(data));
```

to

```
document.write(data);
```

The output HTML document is just:

```
[object Object]
```

Comment: what is the goal here?

Comment: Well, get render the received JSONOBject f rom the Servlet to a Chart.

Comment: document.write will overwrite the whole DOM, do replace this instead and the rest of the code. `data = ($.parseJSON(data));`

Comment: But then one the client side, I get in the HTML document:<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 var data = {"map":{"DeltaRealTime":{"myArrayList":[{"map":{"name":"f1","value":"21","key":"aa1"}},{"map":{"name":"f2","value":"22","key":"aa2"}}]}}};
 document.write(($.parseJSON(data));
    var seriesOptions = [];

       for (i = 0; i < data.DeltaRealTime.length; i++){

Comment: So the chart is not rendered

Comment: you should remove this `document.write(($.parseJSON(data));`. This is replacing your whole DOM.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96570/discussion-between-user3236180-and-joyblanks).

Comment: Can we chat? Cause why is my javascript code not being executed? Can I somehow debug it?